# Do you need to edit the info.plist file for which devices you support?

Tags: ios, xcode

If in `xcode` I set the deployment targets `(iOS 7+ and iPhones)` Do i need to actually go in to the `info.plist` file and specify which devices and `iOS` versions?

Comment: When you set the deployment target you are, in fact, editing the info.plist, using a GUI interface.

Answer (score 0):

No. Xcode is smart enough to update the Info.plist based on the choices you make on the General and Capabilities tabs.

Answer (score 0):

No, normally the only distinction is iPad and/or iPhone.

You'll need to make sure you have 568h images to enable iPhone5 support (as opposed to letter boxing)

In addition, if there are specific capabilities you require (GPS, e.g.) you can use the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

For more information on plist keys available, check out the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)